# Select the same range in multiple workheets

Tags: vba, range, counter

So I need to select the same range **in all worksheets** except "Sheet1". The range is dinamic based on the value "s1" on the column A. So I want to select what is in column B for the value s1, make it bold, then to count the s1 values in column C.
This is what I have so far

[image]

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, yRg As Range, zRg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim C1 As Range



    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
          For Each xRg In Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
            If xRg.Text = "s1" Then
                If yRg Is Nothing Then
                    Set yRg = Range("B" & xRg.Row).Resize(, 1)
                            k = 1
                            For Each cell In yRg
                                yRg.Cells(k, 2) = k
                                yRg.Cells.Select
                                k = k + 1
                             Next cell
                Else
                    Set yRg = Union(yRg, Range("B" & xRg.Row).Resize(, 1))

    If Not yRg Is Nothing Then yRg.Select
For Each C1 In yRg
  C1.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
Next C1
End Sub
```

Comment: `lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, then `For Each xRg In ws.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)`. You must fully qualify all involved ranges... Otherwise, your code works only on the active sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xRg As Range, yRg As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            ws.Cells.Font.Bold = False   ' clear bold formatting for debugging purposes
            Set yRg = Nothing
            For Each xRg In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
                If xRg.Text = "s1" Then
                    If yRg Is Nothing Then
                        Set yRg = xRg.Offset(0, 1)
                    Else
                        Set yRg = Union(yRg, xRg.Offset(0, 1))
                    End If
                    xRg.Offset(0, 2) = yRg.Cells.Count 'set entry number
                End If
            Next xRg
            If Not yRg Is Nothing Then yRg.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

> Before
> [image]

> After
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

A selection or a range does not extend across multiple sheets; there is a selection per sheet. So you need to work within each sheet.

You had a lot of unclosed loops and conditions. This is my best guess at what you were trying to do:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, yRg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim s1count As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Set yRg = Nothing
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each xRg In Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
            If xRg.Text = "s1" Then
                If yRg Is Nothing Then
                    Set yRg = xRg.Offset(0, 1)
                Else
                    Set yRg = Union(yRg, xRg.Offset(0, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next xRg
        If Not yRg Is Nothing Then
            s1count = 0
            For Each cell In yRg
                cell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
                s1count = s1count + 1
                cell.Offset(0, 1) = s1count
            Next cell
        End If
      End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```